# cocoa: which method in cocoa same as animateWithDuration:animations:completion:?

Tags: cocoa

I can implement an animation using animator in mac os cocoa, like

```
[[view animator] setFrame:newFrame];
```

but my problem is I have to animate some points which are properties of view. I can do it like the following iPhone code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                                for (Point point in self.points) {
                                    point.x += 10;
                                }
                           } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                }];
                            }];
```

I want to know how can I do this in mac ox cocoa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for NSView animation you have to override standart animation, that is used by animator.

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.delegate = yourDelegate;
NSDictionary *animations = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:animation,@"frameSize",nil];
[view setAnimations:animations];
```

The key for the animation is the property you want to animate.

If you don't need delegate you can use such code:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
[[view animator] setFrameOrigin:origin];
[CATransaction commit];
```

If you need more complex animations you can create an overlay window with layer hosting contentview and animate layers with a view screenshot inside.

Comment: but what if the property is an array?like view.points? I need to animately every point in view.points array from one position to another position.

Comment: In cocoa for mac you can't animate custom properties with animator. If you need to animate several views, you can invoke each view animation separately. you can create your own animation for custom properties.